# How to render a user defined react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

In my electron application, I want to offer some kind of extensibility for the UI.
The users should be able to create a react component inside of a text editor inside of my application. Their code gets saved to a file. They also can define where the component should be placed inside my UI.

The problem is: I can't seem to figure out how to parse and inject the user-defined JSX in my existing react app.

I thought I try with babel transformSync, but I can't get it working. This is what I have so far:

```
const DynamicComponent = (props) => {
  const reactCode = `
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 >Hello, World!</h1>
      </div>
    )
  `;

  const transpiledCode = transform(reactCode, {
    presets: ["@babel/preset-react"]
  }).code;

  console.log("transpiled", transpiledCode);
  globalThis["React"] = React;
  const Dynamic = new Function(`return ${transpiledCode}`)();
  return <Dynamic />;
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/mobx-state-tree-todolist-3umd4?file=/components/TodoList.js

I'd like to have the "`<h1>Hello, World!</h1>`" rendered below my todo list.

Answer (score 3):

This took sometime. Here are somethings to be aware of:

1. The `@babel/core` gives an invalid version error, so I used the `@babel/runtime` version since it's designed for use in the browser.
2. I found out that removing comments while using the `@babel/core` helped with automatic semicolon insertion problem with js.
3. You need to return your new DynamicComponent directly. Do not convert it to ReactElement by returning `<Dynamic />`.

See codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/mobx-state-tree-todolist-forked-g5n2dn?file=/components/TodoList.js)

```js
const DynamicComponent = (props) => {
  const reactCode = `
       <div>
          <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
        </div>
  `;

  const transpiledCode = transform(reactCode, {
    presets: [
      "react",
      {
        comments: false
      }
    ]
  }).code;

  globalThis["React"] = React;

  return new Function(`return ${transpiledCode}`)();
};
```

Comment: Amazing- I would not have figured it out I think!